# Compiler warns "Value of increment value (bar++) is used" - does this mean the behavior changes?

Tags: java, postfix-operator

When I compile the following piece of code, I got a warning from the compiler saying "Value of increment value (bar++) is used"

```
int foo = 1, bar = 2;
return foo + bar++; // foo and bar are ints
```

So that means the value returned would be `4`, rather than `3`, which is surprising because I was expecting `3`

Is it universal to all java compiler? Or just the one I' using (NetBeans) that's doing something different?

Thanks

Comment: It's universal: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: No. The result will be 3. I think you misread the warning (actually, there is no warning if you compile with javac).

Comment: You're asking what it would return; why not **try it**? It's going to return 3. I highly suspect that eclipse is telling you that it's *unused*, not used.

Comment: When i compile on command prompt i am not getting any warnings

Comment: @Rameshwar.S.Soni - he's talking about his IDE (eclipse) not a compiler warning.

Comment: Is the confusion here because the example above is too trivial (and should "used" be "unused", or is that the point here, that netbeans has a bug in its messaging?)?  Make foo and bar fields, and the return the body of a method,  First time you invoke, you get 3, next time 4, ... yet, for me, eclipse still moans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) All Java compilers will produce the same bytecode for your code and the result will be 3. Just test it.

2) As for the warning, it means that `return foo + bar++`; is the same as `return foo + bar`;

Answer (score 4):

That piece of code says "`return foo + bar`" and then "`increment bar`". So, "`foo + bar`" is `3`, then bar is incremented, but the function has already returned so that's useless.

`variable++` is for post-increment, meaning, "increment the variable after it's done being used in this expression.

If you want the variable incremented before it is used, use the pre-increment operator, `++variable`.

As far as I know, all languages that implement pre/post-increment operators do it this way (although some languages have some ambiguity with how they handle more complicate expressions).

```
% cat Test.java
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("The result is: " + runTest() + "\n");
  }
  public static int runTest() {
    int foo = 1, bar = 2;
    return foo + bar++;
  }
}
% javac Test.java
% java Test
The result is: 3
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question! I know what the code is supposed to do. That is, it is supposed to return `3` (return foo + bar, then increment bar), but I am not seeing that when I execute the code

Comment: If that's not what you are seeing, then what *are* you seeing? Try running my test program